# Problem with makefile in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, make, gcc

I have installed Cygwin. My problem is when I try to run a makefile which contains a line

```
gcc -g -c file.c
```

I get an error:

```
Fatal: Unable to execute command: gcc
```

At the same time when running this command from command line it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The whole file:

```
CFLAGS  = -g
CC      =  gcc

file.o: file.c file.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file.c
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the make file.

Comment: @ceving I have updated my question

Comment: I thought it could be due to your Makefile having DOS line endings, but I just used your Makefile on my Cygwin installation with DOS line endings and with Unix line endings and it worked fine both ways.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Cygwin make? You can check with `which make`.

Comment: @ak2 Thanks! That was the reason. After I installed cygwin make it worked.